# Why is my linear regression data summary displaying the wrong information?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics, linear-regression

I want to find the standard error for my data set that looks like this. The code runs a summary of the dataset,but I am not sure that it is accurate since the y intercept  value is way off, for example, I know that the intercept would be around -5.4 but my code tells me that it is 4. Am I using the **sm.ols** function wrong?

```
dfa=pd.read_csv('F:/data32.csv',parse_dates=['Date'])
print (dfa)
Temperature     unit     unit.1     CO2 flux.1   %Root Resp      CO2-Rh
4.5             umol/m2/s  mg/cm^2/h    0.001210        26.5  0.000889
4.5             umol/m2/s  mg/cm^2/h    0.001339        26.5  0.000984
6.5             umol/m2/s  mg/cm^2/h    0.001339        26.5  0.000984
5.3             umol/m2/s  mg/cm^2/h    0.001469        26.5  0.001080
4.0             umol/m2/s  mg/cm^2/h    0.001598        26.5  0.001175
5.5             umol/m2/s  mg/cm^2/h    0.001598        26.5  0.001175
def summer():
    x=dfa['Temperature']
    y=dfa['CO2-Rh']
    result = sm.ols(formula="x ~ y", data=x).fit()
```

This is the part that gives me the wrong result:

```
    print (result.params)
    print (result.summary())
    fit = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
```

Real slope and intercept:

```
    slope, intercept=np.polyfit(x,y,1) 
    print ('slope=',(slope))
    fit_fn = np.poly1d(fit)
```

is this the real standard error?:

```
    standard_error=stats.sem(fit, axis=None, ddof=0)
    return print ('standard error =',(standard_error))
```

Comment: post q here:   http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You are plotting your "Temperature (X)" data against "CO2-Rh" (Y) and then using linear regression to calculate slope and intercept? I calculate this as: slope: -0.0000094 intercept: 0.001095 Why do you expect intercept to be around 5.4?  (Calculations shared at https://mycurvefit.com/share/33542b9f-716f-4d61-a8e3-d6c2439b1f75)